# Confusion About Char Array to Unsigned Long

Tags: c, arrays, char, int

I am trying to convert the hexadecimal sequence of

```
0x93e1c829
```

to

```
2481047593
```

My hexadecimal sequence is stored in an unsigned character array that when printed looks like `0xf8, 0xff, 0x89, 0x6b`

I used

```
unsigned char number[4]; 
// populate the array
unsigned long expected_value = (unsigned long) (*((unsigned int*) number))
```

I'm fairly certain I'm missing something fairly simple but can't spot it out. The logic above says to me: convert the char array into an integer array then take the value of the integer and cast it into an unsigned long.

However, when I do

```
printf("%lu", expected_value);
```

I get

```
701030803
```

Reference:

Using

http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter

I have found that the expected value is `2481047593`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have actually works but you're running into little-endian/big-endian issues.

The decimal value `701030803` is actually equal to `0x29c8e193`, the hex number you have but in reverse order.

The characters you have are `0x93`, `0xe1`, `0xc8` and `0x29` and that's probably how they're stored in memory but, in a little-endian environment, the higher memory address is the most significant byte.

A quick'n'dirty fix is to simply swap the bytes over before treating it as an integer, or construct it yourself with something like:

```
unsigned long expected_value =
    number[3] << 24 ||
    number[2] << 16 ||
    number[1] <<  8 ||
    number[0];
```

If you're in an environment that provides them (such as POSIX), there are functions to do this work for you, such as [`htonl()`](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html) (host format to network format, long type).

Comment: Rather than quick and dirty, isn't that what the whole `Network Byte Order` suite of functions do?

Comment: @Peter, yes, but they're not part of ISO C. However, I'll mention them as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> My hexadecimal sequence is stored in an unsigned character array that when printed looks like `0xf8, 0xff, 0x89, 0x6b`

I don't understand how these numbers relate to the other numbers given.... but disregarding that, @paxdiablo is correct, 701030803 is the byte-reversed equivalent of 2481047593.  You can either specify the numbers is the reverse order, or... if you have no control over the order of the bytes (say, they are coming from an outside source such as an input file), then you will have to manually reverse the bytes, similar to the following:

```
unsigned char inp[4];
// program populates array inp[]
unsigned char reversed[4] = { inp[3], inp[2], inp[1], inp[0] };
unsigned long expected_value = (unsigned long) (reversed);
```